# Needs an Arabic language package that supports Magento 1.9.2.4

Tags: magento-1.9, language-package

I need an Arabic language package  which supports Magento `1.9.2.4`. So far unable to find it so please help.

Answer (score 1):

Prefer This Link.. 
Download Your Language Packege..

https://github.com/versedi/Magento-Locales/

Answer (score 0):

**First Try This :**

**Step :1)** language Package : http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-saudi-arabia-language-pack.html get key

**Step :2)** Admin panel ->system-> Magento Connect install new language package.

**Step :3)** *Admin panel-> system-> Configuration* -chose you Current Configuration Scope -General -> Locale Options set :Locale Arabic (Saudi Arabia) or your arabic package you chose (Egypt , Morocco ..etc)

**Step :4)** Admin panel -> system -> Cache Management : Flush Magento Cache

**Step :5)** Refresh front page for your store

**Or Try Second Method : Use Below Link:**

https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/magento-community-modules-arabic-standard-language-pack.html

**OR you Can Also goto Below Link :**
http://www.magecloud.net/marketplace/extension/magento-community-modules-arabic-standard-language-pack/

Comment: I tried to install this extension but an error came and server went down

Comment: ok you tried all the option?

Comment: yes... @ H_Parekh